# Is there a way to view Google Maps Traffic Layer using LeafletJS?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, leaflet

I want to implement multi-map support in Leaflet. So far, I've been able to display Google Map tiles. Now I am looking for a way to display the traffic layer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't allow you to use their tiles without using their mapping API. Please see their [General Terms](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/):

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t ... try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.

It's possible to get the tiles without using Google Maps' API, but they may shut off your map without warning:

> We may suspend or stop providing our Services to you if you do not comply with our terms or policies or if we are investigating suspected misconduct.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can´t use their traffic layer.

If you want to show a traffic layer similar to the one that Google provides, you should get a service that provides you the traffic data, then convert that data into poly-lines with different styles (for instance: red for slow traffic areas, etc), create a overlay layer with those poly-lines and then add it to the map using some layer control.